# Add formula and string in cell, libre calc 2017

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I would like to have a cell that has a formula in it (like `=SUM(A1:A5)`) and some text after the formula, with the desired effect of something like:
`50 apples`

What I have tried 
`=SUM(B:B), apples`

Answer (score 1):

Just use the **[`CONCATENATE()`](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc:_CONCATENATE_function)** function:

```
=CONCATENATE(SUM(B:B); " apples")
```

Another solution would be to define a custom number format.